# Java GUI Search Word From File Then Continue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a GUI for user login.

First the user creates his account, and that information is stored in a `.txt` file. I use `PrintWriter` to append details in that file. 
The details are stored using a separator. I can easily read every detail of a user from the file.

In the login UI, I have 2 `JTtextField` components in a `JFrame` the first one for the user name and the second onw for the password.

I get the values using the getText method:

```
String user = user.getText();
String password = password.getText();
```

I tried using `BufferedReader` but I can't get it to work:

```
if(user.equals(br.readline))
```

What i want to do is scan the file and if anything in the file is equal to the username (The getText from user on Frame) then I want to use SetVisible to go to Next Frame

My problem is that even on wrong password and user it go to new frame

How can I fix that?

Code to Check for User and Password, found online on StackOverflow still now working.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Details.txt"));
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    int val =0;
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if(line.indexOf(user)   !=-1   && line.indexOf(pass)   !=-1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login");
        val = 1;
        vf.setVisible(true);
        break;
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid");
        val = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Another Code which is used in for , while even in do while loop , still not working.

```
File file  = new File("Details.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Details.txt"));
String Line;      

do{
    if(user.equals(br.readLine()) && pass.equals(br.readLine())){
        vf.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid");
    }
}while((Line=br.readLine())  !=null )
```

This is how Users Details are Stored in My File.

```
=======================  
=======================  

 First Name = Ahmed Ali 
 Last Name = Qazi
 Address = Al-Abbass Colony pHase 2
 Phone Number = +92032329301
 Email Address = ahmedrider56@gmail.com
 UserName = ahmedfirst67
 Password = dangerd = 2hg

=======================  
=======================  







=======================  
=======================  

 First Name = Ahm345 
 Last Name = Qa345
 Address = Al-asfafs
 Phone Number = +92032329301
 Email Address = ahmgsdg
 UserName = ahmegg
 Password = dagg
```

Comment: Please add the code that checks the file and set the visibility of the second frame to your question and also provide an example of a line in the txt file.

Comment: @Bentaye Done bro u can check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not straightforward given your file structure but you can do it this way:

- Scan the file until you find the username.
- Once you found the user name, keep scanning until you reach the password line.
- Read this password and exit the scanning loop.
- Then compare the given password with the one you found in the file.

Here is the code:

```
private static boolean checkCredentials(String user, String pass) throws IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Details.txt"));

    boolean userFound = false;
    String correctPassword = null;

    String line;
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        line = sc.nextLine();
        // find the user
        if(!userFound) {
            userFound = line.contains("UserName = "+user);
        } else {
            // find the password
            if(line.contains("Password = ")) {
                correctPassword = line.substring(line.indexOf("=") + 2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return correctPassword!=null && correctPassword.equals(pass);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(checkCredentials("Bob", "dagg"));
    System.out.println(checkCredentials("ahmegg", "daggy"));
    System.out.println(checkCredentials("ahmegg", "dagg"));
}
```

This prints:

```
false
false
true
```

Stick it in your code like this:

```
val = 0;
String message = "Invalid";
if(checkCredentials(user, pass)) {
    message = "Login";
    val = 1;
    vf.setVisible(true);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

**NOTE:**

It would be lot easier if you stored the details on one line this way:

```
Ahmed Ali|Qazi|Al-Abbass Colony pHase 2|+92032329301|ahmedrider56@gmail.com|ahmedfirst67|dangerd = 2hg
Ahm345|Qa345|Al-asfafs|+92032329301|ahmgsdg|ahmegg|dagg
```

You could use the `String.split` method to parse each line and get user and password at the same time.

**NOTE 2:**

Also it is very bad practice to store password unencrypted. If this is a school exercise it is fine, but if it is for a real life project, you might want to look at encrypting the passwords in the file.

Comment: Nah its not real project :P

Comment: i know that password should be encrypted :)

Comment: But i don't want value true and false 
I want the Gui to go to next Frame if Useranme and password Is match in the file
so were to put frame.setVisibile(true)  then ?

Comment: well, if it returns true, do `vf.setVisible(true);`, it it returns false, do not do anything

Comment: @AHMEDALI I edited the answer with an example of how to stick it in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the Help

Comment: Really u help alot . by the way , which book u have read?
i want a book in which their should be exercise or Book should explain Things Easily

Comment: @AHMEDALI You're welcome. Unfortunately, I can't really recommend a book, it is mostly experience, I've been working with Java for 10 years.

Comment: oh then u got Nice Experience :) . 
well just need my logics to get clear :P

Comment: i have one more question
how to save radio button or check box data to file??

online solutions not working .
used FileWriter , FileOutputStream , BufferedWriter 
can't think of anything else

so how to write check box or radio box data to txt file?

Comment: @AHMEDALI It depends on what they represent. For the radio, save the index of the selected item, or its value. For a checkbox, save it as a list of indexes or values  (the ones selected) separated by a comma for example

Comment: Didn't understand 
Can i get Any Example??

got  JRadioButton and JCheckBox

Just show me one code Example on one JRadioButton 
And one code Example on JCheckBox

if u can . will be thankful to you

Comment: @AHMEDALI That is a big question if you want examples, and out of scope for this question. You'd better post another question with the code of your radio and checkbox buttons and ask how to save their values in a text file.